# Is this (loose) capacitor critical?

Tags: arduino-mega

I have a Arduino Mega where a capacitor is 'broken off' ... I originally posted the question in the Electronics forum ([Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314084/is-this-solderable/314109#314109)).

One of the answers was that the capacitor is not critical. Can anyone confirm it (and consequences by not fixing it at all)? I didn't dare to turn on the Mega because of the broken capacitor.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You should probably leave the question on EESE where you originally asked it.  You'll get far more credible circuit engineering advice there than here.

Comment: Ok ... I thought it would be more Arduino related.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think it's fine if he leaves this question here. We would probably send him over to you all anyways because it's a question related to an Arduino product and something that is viable to an Arduino system. We would probably tell Michel to check the datasheets.

Comment: @KingDuken - it's *not* a question about using an Arduino as a "product", rather it's a question about the detailed requirements of a particular regulator circuit.  So it really belongs on EESE, not here.  Additionally, this is effectively a cross-site duplicate, something that isn't allowed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Understood. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Downvoter, can you instead of downvoting all my posts, explain WHY you downvoted, so I may improve the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the voltage regulator is a MC33269 as in the official Arduino Mega 2560, then you need that capacitor, or else the MC33269 might start to oscillate. Search in the datasheet of the MC33269 for the paragraph with: "The MC33269 requires an external output capacitor for stability". The board will probably still work without it, but if it does indeed start to oscillate, then it can cause trouble. This is only when powered via the power barrel jack or the VIN pin.

That capacitor does not do a lot when the Arduino Mega is powered via the USB cable. You can use it without any problem when powered via the USB.

According to the photo, you can solder it back into place. They wrote enough about that in the EESE section. Give it a try, but don't create a shortcut with too much solder.

Comment: Thanks ... eventually I want to use a Mega it with a barrel jack, but I will keep this one for only USB purposes (that's fine for me). I will get a replacement anyway and having a 'test' Mega is always convenient.

Comment: Good. What about moving over to 3.3V faster processors ? Like the Arduino Due and Arduino Zero or M0 ?

Comment: I don't understand your remark ... why would I move to 3.3V faster processors? Actually I would like, but I don't want to put all 'new' things in at once (I already am new to Arduino Uno, electronics in general, RF, microcrontrollers, opto-couplers, (S)RAM etc).

Comment: Well, the Uno and Mega are still very useful, but they are slowly fading out in the coming years. It is moving towards 3.3V processors with more memory. Most sensors are 3.3V and a SD memory card is 3.3V and so on. The Raspberry Pi is also 3.3V.

Comment: I already found out that ... I ordered 23LC1024 (128 KB SRAMs) which work on +5 V but +3.3 V is easier too find, and for my RFs (nRF24L01s) I bought breakout boards for +5 -> 3.3 V (same as for WIFI which I just bought for trying). 
But I don't feel confident (yet) to use directly 3.3V directly. And for SD I bought an entire shield since the cheap 'breakout' board did not work that well (maybe for the same reason)